Flutter app development making the audio run even after app lost focus
I am doing a pod talk app but as soon as my app is losing focus the sound switches off. When using any other pod talk app the sound still flows to the headset. How is this achieved in flutter?
I have tried this, Lifecycle of a Widget, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gIbneld-bw
